# Formula result converted to #NAME? in Excel 07 but not 03

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that contains a Bloomberg formula (BLPH) which has to be opened and allowed to calculate on a Bloomberg terminal, saved, and then the user can select the saved file to import the results back at their own PC.

This has always worked fine within Excel 03 as the formula does not attempt to update so stores the returned values which are then imported into a database. However, now we need to use this on Excel 07 machines I am finding the formula result cannot be imported back at the user's PC because the result is automatically converted to a #NAME? error.

Is there a way around this without having to get the user to copy/paste values as this will interfere with some other functionality?

The formula in question is stated as:

```
='C:\blp\API\dde\blph.xla'!BLPH($A2,$B2,$C2,$C2,0,FALSE,"D"," "," ",FALSE,1,1,TRUE," "," "," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into Excel's safety first approach to changes in the calculation engine: when a workbook that was last calculated and saved in a previous version is opened in a later version it automatically does a full calculate.
The only way I know of to bypass this is via a registry change: see
http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecrets.htm

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like exactly what the issue is. I can't enforce the version of Excel on the Bloomberg terminals but exporting the workbook in manual calc mode does get round this. I'll just have to train the users to hit F9 now! Thanks again